Format value on v-model
i want to add a formatter to round the input to two decimals behind the comma,
<q-input :data-testid="'demand_edit_financialExposure_shareFinancingPool_' +index" 
                      :readonly="!value.flagFinancialPool" 
                      dense outlined 
                      v-model="value.shareFinancialPool"
                      :disable="value.isDisabled" 
                      min="0" 
                      type="number" 
                      suffix="%" />

i tried this :modelval(value:any){ return value?Number(value.toFixed(2): 0} with :model-value="modelval(value.shareFinancialPool)" but couldn't bind the input value the model value (it disapear as soon as i click outside the input)
